# How to load WFS in jsFiddle?

Tags: openlayers-2

I'm trying to implement a WFS service in jsFiddle for an OpenLayers map.

It works fine here:
  http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/cql-format.html

My example of it is (the map loads but the filter doesn't):
  http://jsfiddle.net/L7sFY/

But I can't seem to get the filter to work properly.

WFS: 
  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Feature_Service

XML WFS file:
http://demo.opengeo.org/geoserver/wfs?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typename=topp:states&outputFormat=json&format_options=callback:loadFeatures